# Animation gets interrupted, but I want the animation to finish

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to coding and I've been playing around with unity and I've encountered a problem.

My problem is, if I move the player and activate the function `SkillAttack1`, the animation will cancel out and won't complete. Right now, as you see in the code below`if I activate the`SkillAttack1`, it works, but still it won't complete the animation. Also, if I'm pressing the "w" button, for example, for 15 seconds the player gets stuck and moves forward. The only way to play the full animation is not moving, but that's not right.

```
[Animator1][1]
[Animator2][2]
[Animator3][3]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeziY.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/310vz.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOVVu.png






using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{   

public float velocity = 5;
public float turnSpeed = 10;
Vector2 input;
float angle;
Quaternion targetRotation;
public Transform cam;
public Animator anim;
public bool IsAttacking = false;


void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update()
{
    if(Mathf.Abs(input.x) < 0.5 && Mathf.Abs(input.y) < 0.5) return;
    CalculateDirection();
    Rotate();
    Move(); 
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(IsAttacking == false)
    {
        GetInput();
    }
    SkillAttack1();
    SkillAttack2();
}

/// Input based on Horizontal(a,d) and Vertical (w,s) keys
void GetInput()
{
        input.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        input.y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        anim.SetFloat("VelX", input.x);
        anim.SetFloat("VelY", input.y);
}


/// Direction relative to the camera rotation
void CalculateDirection()
{
    angle = Mathf.Atan2(input.x, input.y);
    angle = Mathf.Rad2Deg * angle;
    angle += cam.eulerAngles.y; 
}

/// Rotate toward the calculated angle
void Rotate()
{
    targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, turnSpeed 
* Time.deltaTime);
}

/// This player only move along its own forward axis
void Move()
{
    transform.position += transform.forward * velocity * Time.deltaTime;
}

public void SkillAttack1(){
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("1"))
    { 
        IsAttacking = true;
        StartCoroutine(OnSkillAttack1());
    }
}

public void SkillAttack2()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("2"))
    { 
        anim.SetTrigger("SkillAttack2");
    }
}


public IEnumerator OnSkillAttack1()
{
    anim.SetTrigger("SkillAttack1");
    yield return null;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(15.0f);
    IsAttacking = false;
}
}
```

Comment: Hallo and welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your animation controller is getting overridden by your movement code, when your player sends some input to walk left or right, it sets the VelX and VelY variables on your animation controller. Without access to your controller I can't tell you exactly why it's interrupting the attack, but it's likely you have an interrupt set up that triggers from "any state" when one of those variables is above 0 and transitions into the "walk" animation your controller has.

You'll need to adjust your animation transitions to handle this potential case, or alternatively, prevent movement code triggering during an attack animation.